# How can we copy only the new data items that are added at one node to another node in firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to copy only the new data items that are added on one node to another node. But, it also copies the existing data nodes in the copyto node. Please help how can i achieve that, i am trying to copy in this case qSet3, and any subsequent nodes that are being added at the Questions node to userQuestions node.

```
Questions = mDatabase.child("Questions");
userQuestions = mDatabase.child("UserQuestion").child(PhoneNum).child("userQuestions");
                    moveFirebaseRecord(Questions,userQuestions);
public void moveFirebaseRecord(DatabaseReference fromPath, final DatabaseReference toPath) {
    fromPath.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            toPath.setValue(dataSnapshot.getValue(), new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                    if (databaseError != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "COPY FAILED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "COPY SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onCancelled- copy fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
}
```

[image: Firebase database structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your best option is Database Triggers. You can configure an onCreate trigger and make the copy inside that function.

[Database triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events)

[OnCreate handler](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.RefBuilder#onCreate)